# C# Split a string by a regular expression including regular expressions as separate substrings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a string that will appear character by character on a screen. I made it running, but now I'm facing the issue that when the string has color tags or any other tag, the tag is also written character by character applying its effect only when the tag closes. I was thinking of separating those tags as regex, so I could just put them immediately to make them work properly. for that, I need to do the following.

I have my string

```
string myText = "I'm sorry, you don't have enough <color=#00FF00>energy</color> to continue";
```

Usually when I apply the regex I get

- `"I'm sorry, you don't have enough"`
- `"energy"`
- `"to continue"`

What I need is the following

- `"I'm sorry, you don't have enough"`
- `"<color=#00FF00>"`
- `"energy"`
- `"</color>"`
- `"to continue"`

I need to have the tags in the string array separated from the inner strings. Is there a way to make it possible?

Thanks in advance

I tried using Regex.Split:

```
Regex.Split(myText, @"<.*?>");
```

but I cannot match the regular expression to keep the tags as separated substrings inside the string array

Comment: What library are you using. I'm assuming this is using Razor, but it very well could be an XML markup for apps... or could be just using the console.writeline and altering the colour.

Comment: where is your regex expression? code?

Comment: No, in fact, is for a game using Unity. So I need to separate these tags before to start typing the string char by char

Comment: @duerzd696 Regex.Split(myText, @"<.*?>");

Comment: Where's your string coming from?

Comment: @BillTürstandswithUkraine It's just a string that I have preset on the Game level (As I mentioned in another comment, this text will appear in a game with Unity) so it comes as it is

Comment: Since your strings come from your program and not from user input I'd introduce a separator char which isn't contained in any of your strings (for example `|`) and simply split by that - no regex needed then.

Comment: The thing is that all texts will need to be replaced, which are located in a server and loaded in the game, also is not just a couple of texts... there are hundreds of texts in the game

Comment: @Simon A Carrerio if my answer works for you - please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string myText = @"I'm sorry, you don't have enough <color=#00FF00>energy</color> to continue";

string[] split = Regex.Split(myText, @"(<[^>]+>)");
foreach (string s in split)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```